# position absolute and scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a welcome section(div) over all the other elements in my page.

I use absolute,z-index and opacity.

I don't want any action(click,scroll,title,hover..) with all the other elements which are under the my main div.I only want my main div to be in action and stretch all over my page/screen.

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main-welcome {
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-welcome"></div>

<div class="scroll">
  <a>What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


Why Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Where can I get some?
There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected hu</a>
</div>
```

But when I open chrome developer tool and select responsive mode.I can scroll my scroll div which is under main div.

Again I don't want any css/html action with the other elements.

Any idea for solution?

Comment: I think the solution is `position: fixed`

Comment: Maybe.But why ?

Comment: instead of put absolute you can set the position fixed, so the overlay is always scrolling with you. So nobody can interact with behind the elements (because your width/height is 100%)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scroll, change position to relative in `.container`

```
position: relative;
```

Or you don't want to see the scroller. If this is the case

In .scroll just change to:

```
.scroll{

width:90%;
overflow-y:scroll;

}
```

Then you never see the scroller no matter how you resize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to disable pointer events on your `.scroll`:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

This may still allow scrolling in some environments, but should stop all the others.

The other, more reliable method, will be to intercept all of the events and prevent them from doing things.

If `.scroll` was a child of `.main`, you could also use `.stopPropagation()` to intercept them as well.